# Runtime Error after Button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

this is how when I need to create user into my database you will see it with a runtime error, and it only appears when I click the button.

problems are just the only appears when I click the button on the page.

Here we have c # code from opretbruger.aspx.cs

```
protected void ButtonOpretbruger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string fejl = "Hov Hov, Du skal læse vore betingelser";

   if (CheckBoxBetingelser.Checked)
   {
      LabelError.Visible = false;
      cmd.Connection = conn;

      string brugernavn = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxBrugernavn.Text);
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, brugernavn, rank FROM brugere WHERE brugernavn = @brugernavn";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugernavn", brugernavn);

      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (reader.Read())
      {
         LabelErrorBesked.Text = "Hov hov, denne her email er optaget " + brugernavn;
      }
      else
      {
         conn.Close();

         cmd.Connection = conn;

         //ligger noget sikkert på password
         string brugernavn1 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxBrugernavn.Text);
         string adgangskode = Hash.getHashSha256(TextBoxAdgangskode.Text);

         string fornavn = TextBoxFornavn.Text;
         string efternavn = TextBoxEfternavn.Text;

         cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO brugere (brugernavn, adgangskode, fornavn, efternavn) 
           VALUES (@brugernavn, @adgangskode, @fornavn, @efternavn);";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugernavn", brugernavn1);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adgangskode", adgangskode);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fornavn", fornavn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@efternavn", efternavn);

         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Close();

         Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      LabelError.Text = fejl;
   }
}
```

here we have html from opretbruger.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonOpretbruger" runat="server" CssClass="btn pi-btn-base pi-btn-wide pi-weight-600" OnClick="ButtonOpretbruger_Click" ValidationGroup="opretbruger" />
```

The problem is it appears here typing this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

in my web.config looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
    <!--<globalization uiCulture="da" culture="da-DK" />-->
  </system.web>
```

**EIDT UPDATE**

```
protected void ButtonOpretbruger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string fejl = "Hov Hov, Du skal læse vore betingelser";

   if (CheckBoxBetingelser.Checked)
   {
      LabelError.Visible = false;
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = conn;

      string brugernavn = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxBrugernavn.Text);
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, brugernavn, rank FROM brugere WHERE brugernavn = @brugernavn";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugernavn", brugernavn);

      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (reader.Read())
      {
         LabelErrorBesked.Text = "Hov hov, denne her email er optaget " + brugernavn;
      }
      else
      {
         conn.Close();

         SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
         cmd1.Connection = conn;

         string adgangskode = Hash.getHashSha256(TextBoxAdgangskode.Text);

         string fornavn = TextBoxFornavn.Text;
         string efternavn = TextBoxEfternavn.Text;

         cmd1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO brugere (brugernavn, adgangskode, fornavn, efternavn) 
           VALUES (@brugernavn, @adgangskode, @fornavn, @efternavn);";
         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@brugernavn", brugernavn);
         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@adgangskode", adgangskode);
         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@fornavn", fornavn);
         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@efternavn", efternavn);

         conn1.Open();
         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn1.Close();

         Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      LabelError.Text = fejl;
   }
}
```

Error are: **The variable name '@brugernavn' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Must declare the scalar variable "@adgangskode".**

Comment: Get the page from the server console, or set `mode=Off` to get the full error message. Put it here and we will see.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Where i add it ??, Should I write it into the web.config?, Im New on Asp.net & C#

Comment: Yes please. Add the XML config part in the error message.

Comment: it error are **The variable name '@brugernavn' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Must declare the scalar variable "@adgangskode".**

Comment: @PatrickHofman I for no XML files on the server or since.

Comment: The `web.config` file is an XML file. See my answer though.

Answer (score 3):

You are reusing the same command (variable named `cmd`) twice. That is the cause of your error since your previous code interferes with your later code.

Split the `cmd` variable in two. One for the first statement, one for the second.

---

This should be the full code:

```
protected void ButtonOpretbruger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string fejl = "Hov Hov, Du skal læse vore betingelser";

   if (CheckBoxBetingelser.Checked)
   {
      LabelError.Visible = false;

      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
      {
          conn.Open();

          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
          {
              cmd.Connection = conn;

              string brugernavn = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxBrugernavn.Text);
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, brugernavn, rank FROM brugere WHERE brugernavn = @brugernavn";
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugernavn", brugernavn);

              using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  if (reader.Read())
                  {
                     LabelErrorBesked.Text = "Hov hov, denne her email er optaget " + brugernavn;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
                     {
                         cmd1.Connection = conn;

                         string adgangskode = Hash.getHashSha256(TextBoxAdgangskode.Text);

                         string fornavn = TextBoxFornavn.Text;
                         string efternavn = TextBoxEfternavn.Text;

                         cmd1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO brugere (brugernavn, adgangskode, fornavn, efternavn) 
                           VALUES (@brugernavn, @adgangskode, @fornavn, @efternavn);";
                         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@brugernavn", brugernavn);
                         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@adgangskode", adgangskode);
                         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@fornavn", fornavn);
                         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@efternavn", efternavn);

                         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     }

                     Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
                  }
              }
           }
        }

        conn.Close();
      }
   else
   {
      LabelError.Text = fejl;
   }
}
```

Comment: ... and start using using{} blocks for IDisposables.

Comment: Stop using `AddWithValue` :)

Comment: Indeed. I think OP violates almost every rule. At least he does use parameters :)

Comment: Are you sure you split the two? Is the error exact the same, at the same location?

Comment: @JesperPetersen: Sorry, but I'd like to keep it on-site here. Can you post your current code? (Please update your answer)

Comment: @JesperPetersen: Added full code. Can't test it of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with cmd object. That object is used many time and each time you have updated same object. In such case it may possible  that you might add same parameter twice.

Instead of that try to get command following way

```
Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
```

//Now use your cmd over here.